# Smooth, approximately space-filling curves in high dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, curves, smooth-functions

I'm looking for smooth (infinitely differentiable everywhere) functions (curves) $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ that are approximately space-filling, i.e. scaling allows the curve to eventually get arbitrarily close to all points in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

An intuitive example for $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ would be the [Archimedean Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral), e.g.:

[image]

Example function:

$$
\mathrm{f}(t)=
\rho\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos(t) \cdot t \\
  \sin(t) \cdot t
\end{pmatrix}
$$

As $\rho$ approaches zero, the spiral will eventually get arbitrarily close to every point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It would also be great if the computational complexity of calculating such a function only increases linearly with the dimension $d$.

Comment: I have examples that are continuous but not smooth, based on covering size-$2n-1$ hypercubes such that the end point is on the hypercube surface, and then stepping outward and covering the surface of the size-$2n+1$ hypercube. The smoothness requirement makes this a very intriguing question.

Comment: Nice question. Is self-intersection allowed? Also do you require the convergence to be "uniform"?

Comment: @RobArthan Though self-intersection would not pose a technical problem for my application, it would seem preferable if there were no redundancies in the way the curve explores the space.

Comment: I see. How about the convergence? I don't think the Spiral of Archimedes gives uniform convergence.

Comment: @RobArthan I don't make any assumptions about limits of $\mathrm{f}$.  E.g. a point in $\mathbb{R}^d$ may be equally distant to different parts of the curve, or a limit for $t$ that gives you the closest point along the curve may not exist as you increase the density of the curve.  All I need is that the curve can at least in principle be made to wiggle through space so densely that at least one point anywhere along the curve will come arbitrarily close to any point in space.

Answer (score 2):

I have it!

The idea is to multiply a parameter $t^{\frac1{d+1}}$ by various periodic functions of arguments that depend non-linearly on $t$ and contain coefficients which are not rationally related.  Then eventually any spot in space gets approached arbitrarily closely, yet in more than 2 dimensions the curve is non-intersecting.

The example I have in mind is something like:
$$
x = \sqrt[4]{t} \sin \left( t + \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \\
y = \sqrt[4]{t}  \cos \left( \sqrt{3}t + t^2 \right) \\
z = \sqrt[4]{t} \sin  \left( \pi  t^2 \right)
$$
The low-radius area gets filled fairly thoroughly because the curve keeps zipping through it when all the periodic functions coincide near zero.  And that statement appears to be scale independent.

The reason that $t^{\frac{1}{d+1}}$ is used is so that the (hyper)volume being traversed grows more slowly than the length of curve within that volume. That may or may not be a necessity.

I would have difficulty with a rigorous proof for any given fixed $\epsilon$ and any point $\vec{x}$ there exists some $\delta(\epsilon,\vec{x})$ such that the curve intersects an $\epsilon$-ball about $\vec{x}$ for some $t < \delta$ but for generic (non-special) choices of the coefficients in the periodic functions I would be shocked to learn that "holes" exist.

Comment: Thanks, this proposal seems interesting.  Visualizing it, the curve definitely seems to cover 3D space well, even without multiplying by $t^{\frac{1}{d+1}}$.  That factor would not work well for me anyway, because $d$ can be extremely large in my application (possibly millions).  It would be nice if randomly chosen hypervolumes of the same size had the same expected length of curve going through it as seems to be the case for Archimedes in 2D.  I also wished there were a principled way of constructing the function (choosing appropriate coefficients).